# onTextChangeListener with searchView in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, searchview

I'm using a `SearchView` in my application. Now I just want to get the text typed in the `SearchView` and do something this it. But I don't want to use any extra buttons. I just want to get the result when I'm typing in `SearchView` box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's will solve some thing like this in kotlin :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
            // do your work ..
            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onQueryTextChange()`.

For example:

```kotlin
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                // Called when the user submits the query.
                return false
            }
 
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                // Called when the query text is changed by the user.
                return false
            }
})
```

You can check for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener